# Flask is not retrieving data from phpadmin

Tags: python, mysql, flask

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30IYK.jpg)
I have a table in php admin under dms database. I want to display all the rows and columns from patients tables under dms table. My code is not displaying anything on my homepage except the title and heading. My code is here:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
    
app = Flask(__name__)
    
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = ''
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'hms'
    
mysql = MySQL(app)    
    
@app.route('/')
def Home():
  cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
  cur.execute("SELECT * FROM patients")
  Fdata = cur.fetchall()
  cur.close()
    
  return render_template('home.html', data=Fdata)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: List your home.html template.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hospital Management</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{url_for('static', filename = 'HM.png' )}}">
</head>
<body>
<h1 style="background-color: #ffe6e6; text-align:center" > Welcome To Hospital Management System</h1>
</body>
</html>

Comment: It seems you are not using the *data* (the last argument of render_template call) value inside the template.

Comment: I used it Fdata as data

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <title>Hospital Management</title> 
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{url_for('static', filename = 'HM.png' )}}"> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <h1 style="background-color: #ffe6e6; text-align:center" > Welcome To Hospital Management System</h1> 
    <table>
        <tr><th>Title Row 0</th></tr>
        {% for row in data %} 
            <tr><td>{{row[0]}}</td></tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Take a look at *data* use. It's using [Jinja template](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#:%7E:text=A%20Jinja%20template%20is%20simply%20a%20text%20file.&text=A%20template%20contains%20variables%20and,inspired%20by%20Django%20and%20Python).